# Отслеживание изменений в БД Firebase REST API

Tags: javascript, база-данных, api, rest, firebase

Есть ли в Firebase встроенные методы для отслеживания изменений в базе данных с использованием REST API? Читал документацию и английские форумы. Конкретного решения не нашел.

Comment: Вот, вроде, то, что вам нужно: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming

Comment: @ЮрийСПб♦,  я натыкался на это решение, но к сожалению не совсем разобрался с реализацией, так как еще мало опыта в этом. Не могли бы вы подсказать более конкретно как это реализовать?

Comment: Сам такое не реализовывал, засим подсказать с кодом не смогу. Вообще, дока выглядит достаточно подробной. Возможно, вам будет проще, если вы воспользуетесь либой официальной для этого, если, конечно, вы бэк часть пишете: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-event-types

Comment: @ЮрийСПб♦, хорошо, спасибо большое